# How do I synchronize a Palm PDA with Evolution 2.30?

Tags: 10.10, evolution, sync

Ubuntu 10.04 allowed me to sync my Palm PDA (such as memos, calendar, address book) with Evolution using Gnome Pilot.  However, in 10.10, the options for Evolution syncing in Gnome Pilot no longer exist.

Having Googled my issue, it seems Evolution 2.30 was built without the "--with-pilot-conduits" flag.
(http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/xsoft/evolution.html)

Is there a way I can either install a version of Evolution built with support for Gnome Pilot (preferably from a .deb file or repository), or compile it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the excellent steps by andrewsomething and from [Wu Wei Wiki](http://sarakinas.wu.cz/doku.php?id=evo-pilot), I've made a script to automatically download the source code, edit the build flags, and compile it.  [enable-evolution-conduits.sh](https://zorro.casa/go/db/Hosting/Utilities/enable-evolution-conduits.sh)

**Precompiled .debs**

**32bit:** debs are on the [Wu Wei Wiki blog](http://sarakinas.wu.cz/doku.php?id=evo-pilot) at the top of the page.

**64bit:** [evolution-debs.tar.gz](https://zorro.casa/go/db/Hosting/Utilities/evolution-debs.tar.gz)

Once you install all of the deb files, log out then log back in to finish.

**Building from source**

Save [enable-evolution-conduits.sh](https://zorro.casa/go/db/Hosting/Utilities/enable-evolution-conduits.sh) and set it as executable.  (*Right-click the file, go to Properties.  Click the Permissions tab, and check the box "Allow executing file as program"*)

Double-click the file, and choose "Run in Terminal", and supply your password when asked.  It may take up to an hour to compile Evolution.  To finish installing the compiled debs, you might have to enter your password again.  When complete, log out then log back in.

Comment: Glad it worked out. If you're scripting this, you might want to generalize the "→ Bumping version number..." step a bit. For instance: http://paste.ubuntu.com/513524/

Comment: Mind if I update the shell script with your code?

Comment: Not at all; go for it.

Comment: Works for me :D
God thanks, no longer it is needed to change to some useless smart-phone :)

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't tell you if that is indeed the problem, as I don't own a palm device, but I can confirm by looking at evolution's build log that that flag was not passed. http://paste.ubuntu.com/512047/

If you'd like to try building evolution with that flag, here are some steps.

```
apt-get source evolution # Download the evolution source package
sudo apt-get build-dep evolution # Install all of evolution's build dependencies
sudo apt-get install devscripts # Tools for working with Debian packages
sudo apt-get install libgnome-pilot2-dev # Extra build dependency need for the "--with-pilot-conduits" flag.
```

Next, you want to edit the `debian/rules` file. Find the section that looks like:

```
DEB_CONFIGURE_EXTRA_FLAGS += \
    --with-openldap \
    --enable-nls \
    --disable-scrollkeeper \
    --disable-pilot-conduits \
    --with-krb5=/usr \
    --sysconfdir=/etc \
    --libexecdir=/usr/lib \
    --enable-plugins=experimental \
    --enable-python \
    --disable-pst-import \
    --disable-image-inline \
    --disable-contacts-map
```

And replace the `--disable-pilot-conduits \` flag with `--enable-pilot-conduits \`

You'll probably want to bump the version number in `debian/changelog` as well. You can do that by hand, or run something like `dch -v 2.30.3-1ubuntu6+pilot-build -m "Enable pilot-conduits"`

Next, the line `debian/tmp/usr/share/gnome-pilot` must be added to the `debian/evolution-common.install` file and `debian/tmp/usr/lib/evolution/2.30/conduits/*.so` must be added to `debian/evolution.install`

Then you can build the package by running `debuild` from inside the `evolution-2.30.3` directory. Finally, install the resulting debs.

Comment: Thank you very much!  The steps worked, except that the flag is actually '–enable-pilot-conduits', and 'debian/tmp/usr/share/gnome-pilot' must be added to debian/evolution-common.install and 'debian/tmp/usr/lib/evolution/2.30/conduits/*.so' must be added to debian/evolution.install, as per (http://sarakinas.wu.cz/doku.php?id=evo-pilot).  The 'apt-get build-dep' trick is very handy :)