# How to synchronize a Palm PDA with Evolution 2.32.2

Tags: 11.04, evolution

The solution provided for [10.10 and Evolution 2.30](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6267/how-do-i-synchronize-a-palm-pda-with-evolution-2-30) doesn't seem to work because the '–enable-pilot-conduits' option is no longer recognized:

`configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-pilot-conduits`

Is there any other solution ? Many thanks in advance,

--Marc

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [PDA sync support](http://osdir.com/ml/evolution-list/2011-05/msg00032.html) was moved out of Evolution 2.32 into the `gnome-pilot` package.

If you install this package it should enable your PDA to connect and provides expense, memo, time, and email sync functionality.

Comment: Thanks fossfreedom, but that change was already operated in 2.30 release and I had to recompile Evolution with the --enable-pilot-conduits as indicated in the referred post. The problem with 2.32 is that this option is no longer available so gnome-pilot, installed and working fine, cannot "talk" to Evolution...

Comment: have you got both `gnome-pilot` and `gnome-pilot-conduits` installed?  The conduits package should be the one that is the interface between evolution now and your PDA.

Comment: I have 2.32.1-1 for conduits and 2.32.0-1 for pilot. It is explicitly mentioned in the change log of Evolution that the option is useless. This is confirmed by the output I posted. Do you know if I can get back to Evolution 2.30.x under 11.04 ? Do I also have to change the evolution-data-server from 2.32.x to 2.30.x ? Thanks for the help anyway. I feel quite alone in this "pilot" drop decision!

Comment: Hi Marc - the reason why I mentioned the to packages above was because of this archlinux link (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Palm_Evolution) - see the section setting up synchronization.  To my mind - it should in theory work.  As to running evolution 2.30 in natty - that is a good question in its own right so perhaps create a question - link back to this and the original maverick one as well.